# Get Volume group attributes to be used in condition using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to be able to get list of volume groups available and then use the attributes of the volume group to conditionally create  the filesystem on volume which meets the Criteria

Criteria
1: Volume must not have name root in it
2: Volume must be at-least 2 GB

I have this logic

```
- name: list volume groups
  debug: msg="echo volume groups is  {{ item }}" 
  with_items: "{{ ansible_lvm.vgs }}
```

But am struggling to get that attribute of the vgs.

Here is snippet of ansible_lvm

```
"ansible_lvm": {
            "lvs": {
                "lvud01": {
                    "size_g": "0.50",
                    "vg": "vgud01"
                },
                "root": {
                    "size_g": "79.01",
                    "vg": "precise32"
                },
                "swap_1": {
                    "size_g": "0.75",
                    "vg": "precise32"
                }
            },
            "vgs": {
                "precise32": {
                    "free_g": "0",
                    "num_lvs": "2",
                    "num_pvs": "1",
                    "size_g": "79.76"
                },
                "vgud01": {
                    "free_g": "0.50",
                    "num_lvs": "1",
                    "num_pvs": "1",
                    "size_g": "1.00"
                }
            }
```

Comment: `ansible_lvm.vgs` is a dictionary. So try using `with_dict` instead of `with_items` in your task. You can then access the dict key (like precise32 or vgud01) via `{{ item.key }}` and the values through `{{ item.value.free_g }}`. You could then use a conditional `when` in your task to determine whether the drive contains root in it: `when: "not {{ item.key }} == 'root'"`.

Comment: sorry wrong syntax. I meant `when: "{{ not item.key == 'root' }}"`

Comment: Gret that solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just for everyones benefit and thanks @fishi

```
- name: list volume groups
      debug: msg="echo volume groups is  {{ item.key }} has {{ item.value.free_g }}" 
      with_dict: "{{ ansible_lvm.vgs }}"
      when: not item.key  == "root"
```

Answer (score 1):

For those like me taken here by Google and wondering where this `ansible_lvm` dict comes from :

- it is part of the facts gathered by the `setup` module
- it is collected only when executed with super-user privileges

In other words, to get `ansible_lvm` :

- with an *ad-hoc* command (the ✨magic✨ lies in the `-b`) :

  `ansible myManagedNode -m setup -kK -b`
- within a *playbook* :

  ```
  - hosts: myManagedNode
    become: yes
    tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_lvm
  ```